# Force Update from a filtered DataGridView to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have created an application to fix a date conversion problem when transferring data from the machines. The conversion works great. I create a DataGridView that contains all records. I then sort the DataGridView to display the data that needs updating using SqlDataAdapter and DataSet. I then make the changes to the data in the DataGridView and click a save button to apply changes to the database table.

```
     try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Complete");
            this.log5DataGridView.EndEdit();
            //this.log5BindingSource.DataSource = this.log5DataGridView.DataSource; <-- Last Resort
            this.log5BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            this.log5BindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.log5TableAdapter.Update(roboticlineDataSet.Log5);
        }
        catch { }
```

When I run in debug mode the log5DataGridView.DataSource Table[] shows the data changes are available. But the log5BindingSource never seems to get the changes to push it through to the TableAdapter Update. I tried the  ResetBindings, EndEdit() the last thing is to take the Datasource and force it to the BindingSource.

If I use the following code to search for the precise record the save / update to database will not occur.

```
 using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[RoboticLine] WHERE [FSItemNumber] = '" + Value + "' ORDER BY [FSItemNumber] ASC;", conn))
                        {
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            adpt.Fill(ds);
                            valueComboBox.Enabled = false;
                            log5DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                            log5DataGridView.Refresh();
                            this.log5DataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = true;
                        }//end of adpt using
```

The Question is if there is a way to save the searched log5DataGridView record back to the database as the datagridview table retains the change but the log5BindingSource still contains the original

```
this.log5TableAdapter.Fill(this.roboticlineDataSet.Log5);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Of course using an empty try/catch is the perfect way to hide any exceptions and leaving everyone in the dark about any potential errors. I would suggest to remove that empty try/catch

Comment: the empty try/catch can get filed with Exception or DBCurrency and Finally. This is not the issue the Issue is stated above. Data changes are not passing from the datagridview to the bindingsource.. Removing the try catch still lets it run throught the program till the end with nothing occurring.

Comment: the empty try/catch is used in debug mode so whatever exception occurs it can be stopped and handled instead of continuing thru the code with bad data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was occurring, when I programmed the datagridview to show the searched data it did not change the bindingsource but left it the same from the Form Load ().

```
this.log5TableAdapter.Fill(this.roboticlineDataSet.Log5);
```

To resolve this I found the RoboticLineTable in the Dataset.xsd location in the Soultion Explorer. Here I selected the roboticlinetableadapter and right-clicked where i selected Add->Query. Here I created a SQL query with a where ID = @Value  to do the required filtering / search. This replaces the using SqlDataAdapter code with this code

```
this.log5DataGridView.EndEdit();
this.log5BindingSource.EndEdit();    
this.log5tableAdapter.FillByID(this.roboticline.Log5, Value);
this.invalidate();
this.log5DatagridView.Refresh();
```

Now when I wish to save, the BindingSource has the changes made in the datagridview  and update / save to the Database. Creating and refilling the tableadapter helps keep the link to the bindingsource for you.

Hope this helps someone else that may run into this in the future